# How to let Ansible multiline with > ignore spaces in the lines?

Tags: ansible, yaml

## Question

To make indentations in a line line command, would like to put spaces at the subsequent lines of a command split into multiple lines.

```
- name: "Update kubeconfig to set cluster"
  shell: >
    kubectl config set-cluster {{ item.cluster }}
      --kubeconfig=~{{ item.account }}/.kube/config
      --server={{ K8S_MASTER_HOSTNAME }}:{{ K8S_API_SERCURE_PORT }}
      --embed-certs=true
      --certificate-authority={{ K8S_CA_HOME }}/ca.crt
  with_items: "{{ k8s_users }}"
```

Is there a way to allow this? It causes an error and regard each line as a separate command.

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh: line 1: --kubeconfig=~centos/.kube/config: No such file or directory\n/bin/sh: line 2: --server=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:6443: command not found\n/bin/sh: line 3: --embed-certs=true: command not found\n/bin/sh: line 4: --certificate-authority=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: No such file or directory",
"stderr_lines": [
    "/bin/sh: line 1: --kubeconfig=~centos/.kube/config: No such file or directory",
    "/bin/sh: line 2: --server=ip-172-31-4-117.us-west-1.compute.internal:6443: command not found",
    "/bin/sh: line 3: --embed-certs=true: command not found",
    "/bin/sh: line 4: --certificate-authority=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: No such file or directory"
],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a YAML syntax and indentation in YAML is significant. For a block scalar marked with `>` you should use a single indentation level (otherwise YAML parser treats the indented lines as separate ones):

```
- name: "Update kubeconfig to set cluster"
  shell: >
    kubectl config set-cluster {{ item.cluster }}
    --kubeconfig=~{{ item.account }}/.kube/config
    --server={{ K8S_MASTER_HOSTNAME }}:{{ K8S_API_SERCURE_PORT }}
    --embed-certs=true
    --certificate-authority={{ K8S_CA_HOME }}/ca.crt
  with_items: "{{ k8s_users }}"
```

Or you can use plain style flow scalar:

```
- name: "Update kubeconfig to set cluster"
  shell: kubectl config set-cluster {{ item.cluster }}
           --kubeconfig=~{{ item.account }}/.kube/config
           --server={{ K8S_MASTER_HOSTNAME }}:{{ K8S_API_SERCURE_PORT }}
           --embed-certs=true
           --certificate-authority={{ K8S_CA_HOME }}/ca.crt
  with_items: "{{ k8s_users }}"
```